# JavaScript Namespace with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you manage namespace for a custom JavaScript library depends on jQuery?

Do you create your own namespace, say `foo` and add your objects there? e.g. `foo.myClass, foo.myFunction`

Or do you add your objects to jQuery's namespace? e.g. `jQuery.myClass, jQuery.myFunction`

Which is the more common practice and why?

Comment: LOL don't add your properties to jQuerys namespace...

Comment: Dive into RequireJS for non-jQuery plugin management ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would depend on what the library does.

- If you're extending the functionality of instances of jQuery objects, you'd use `jQuery.fn` as was described very nicely by [@David Titarenco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243613/david-titarenco) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838876/javascript-namespace-with-jquery/4838907#4838907).
- If you're creating utilities that are meant to be seen as additions to those provided in `window.jQuery`, then I don't see a problem with using that namespace (as long as you're careful with naming).
- If it is really its own separate library that is *not* meant to be seen as an extension of jQuery, yet relies on functionality from jQuery, then definitely use your own namespace.

Answer (score 7):

[This article](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) discusses writing jQuery plugins/libraries in excruciating detail.

What NOT to do:

```
(function( $ ){

  $.fn.tooltip = function( options ) { // THIS };
  $.fn.tooltipShow = function( ) { // IS   };
  $.fn.tooltipHide = function( ) { // BAD  };
  $.fn.tooltipUpdate = function( content ) { // !!!  };

})( jQuery );
```

What to do:

```
(function( $ ){

  var methods = {
    init : function( options ) { // THIS },
    show : function( ) { // IS   },
    hide : function( ) { // GOOD },
    update : function( content ) { // !!! }
  };

  $.fn.tooltip = function( method ) {

    // Method calling logic
    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
    }    

  };

})( jQuery );
```

I also wrote a [blog post](http://dvt.name/post/how-to-namespace-javascript/) last year about various methods for namespacing in JavaScript (non-jQuery related).

Comment: Your site has been hijacked. Pages at dvt.name redirect to baaaaddd places.