# Embed jQuery in own module

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a JavaScript component which depends on jQuery. The problem here is, that I'd like to provide the component in such a way, that the user who uses my component doesn't have to care about dependencies (like jquery); the user just have to include my script into the html file. An other problem is, that the user may use jQuery in his own scripts, so that there are multiple instances of jQuery included.

My solution for that is this:

```
var myscope = (function () {

    // PASTE the minfied jQuery Code (and plugins) here!!!
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict(true);

    return { // public stuff

    }

})();
```

Do you have any recomendations or ideas to do it better?

//Edit:
The user shouldn't even know (excepts he reads the source code of my component) that the component depends on jquery.

Best regards.

Comment: Use a module loading library like http://requirejs.org/

Comment: May also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838876/javascript-namespace-with-jquery

Comment: A module loading library is not a solution, because its up to the user of my component if he/she likes to use something like that. In most cases, the user adds a <script src="..."> tag to the html page and that's it.

Comment: if people aren't smart enough to add their own script tags in for jQuery, i've lost faith in this profession for sure

Comment: @Chimoo, that's not the point here. The component is intended to be like 'google maps' where the inexperienced user puts just 2 lines of code into his page and that's all to get complete functionality. The component is not intended to be used by professionals.

Comment: I see...then you need to do something like `if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') { document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='URL to jquery' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E")); }`

Comment: That's quite good... but what to do, if the user actually uses jQuery and includes it AFTER my module has been included?

Comment: then your code will have already run? if you're worried their code will break, put a $.noConflict(true) at the end of your code, if that original if statement was true.

Comment: Yup, sure... but it's an interactive component I'm working on. So MY COMPONENTS VERSION of jQuery is still needed after the whole site has been loaded. jQuery adds "jQuery" and "$" to the global namespace. If the user adds an older version of jQuery than my component, my component won't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comments...

```
var removejQuery = false;
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') { 
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='URL to jquery' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E")); 
    removejQuery = true;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   //your library here

    if (removejQuery) $.noConflict(true);
});
```

let me know if it works

Comment: Thank you... I'm working on a solution considering your code. I will let you know about the results.

Comment: i have a feeling the problems you are describing are the reasons twitter, google, facebook et al all simply print an iframe onto the page. is that feasible?